# Adding a block where an admin can create users on the fly

Tags: users, 8, blocks

What methods are there for creating users on the fly for Drupal 8 in a block? I'm creating a page where the admin can create content, but also there is a user reference field. I currently have it expose current users in the system that you can choose from. In order for me to create a new user to the list, I have to goto the admin/people/create page, but what methods are there to expose this user creation form on the content creation page?

I tried inline_entity_form but that doesn't work as it is still in alpha. It's best if I can just do this in core. Ajax isn't necessary as reloading the page is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a great opportunity for you to learn how to write a custom block, and a custom form in it:

1. Create a new block in one of your module
2. Create a custom form in it.
3. Place your block somewhere in your page. You are done!

For both block and form creation there are nice articles just for Drupal 8.

Good luck!